# How can I use the debugger on a Spring Boot application for the Google App Engine (standard)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2 app that I've configured to run on the Google App Engine (standard, not the flex).

I've configured it to the point that I can run it from the command line (mvn appengine:run) and I can deploy it (mvn appengine:deploy) successfully.

I use STS (Eclipse) for my development, so I want to run it in that environment and run the debugger in it.
I have the maven plugin for eclipse installed, so I created a Maven configuration with the appengine:run goal, and so I'm able to run my app in Eclipse successfully.

However, when I run that goal through the "debug app" icon at the top of the window, the breakpoints don't drop me into the debugger.

What should I do to be able to run the debugger with my app?

This is what I tried:

1. Add -Xdebug to the vm args in the Run configuration
2. Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse Plugin: the plugin has an icon at the top that
   allows for "Debug on App Engine...", but it's unfortunately grayed
   out for my project. I tried "Configure -> Convert to App Engine
   Standard Project" and it started modifying some of my files only
   to abort mid way with a NullPointerException, leaving my environment
   in an undefined state.
3. Running from Eclipse with "Run as Spring Boot App...": the issue is that my pom.xml had to be heavily modified to get to run a Spring Boot App in app engine, and so running as Spring Boot App doesn't work anymore.

Comment: About Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse, could you file a new issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues) with details so that we can fix it? We can continue conversation there, and there may be a workaround too.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to debug a Spring Boot application with the [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/). All I did was:

1. Modify the Spring Boot app according to [this procedure](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard#steps-to-convert-a-spring-boot-application-for-app-engine-standard) (you already performed this step, just for reference).
2. Upload the complete project to a git repo. You can choose local files as well.
3. Go to the GOOGLE APP ENGINE services list in the console and click on `Tools -> Debug`:

[image]

4. Choose the folder that contains your project files:

[image]

5. After this you can set your breakpoints in your code and debug your application.

See the guides at:

- https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#gae-standard
- https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/java#gae-flex